# MySQL locate or remove string suffix from a known set

Tags: mysql

I want to write a MySQL stored procedure which will split a FQDN into host/authority/tld parts.

Let's say I have a list of known TLDs, and for the sake of illustration let's say it's the set

```
com
co.uk
uk
```

let's test it against these strings

```
input           | output
----------------|-------
alpha.co.uk     | alpha
mail.beta.uk    | mail.beta
```

The output is the *shortest* substring of the input, starting from the beginning, such that `CONCAT(output,'.',tld)=input` for some `tld` which is a member of the given set.

Note that we need the shortest substring as the output, otherwise the output would be `alpha.co` in the first case, which is wrong.

I know how to write a MySQL function which tells me whether a given string is the suffix of another string, but here there are many possible such strings and any will do (provided no longer string is also a suffix of the input).

I know I could write a regex along the lines of `co\.uk|uk|com` but MySQL `REGEX` operator does not return the *position* of the match, just whether it matches or not.

Yes, I really do want a solution in SQL for this, not in the application language.

What's the best way to locate or remove the longest possible suffix, given a set of valid suffixes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do that, relying on the fact that MIN() will yield the shortest of all the matches:

```
create table tld (tld varchar(100));
create table input (input varchar(100));

insert into tld values ('com'),('co.uk'),('uk');
insert into input values ('alpha.co.uk'),('mail.beta.com');

select 
    input.input as input, 
    min(substring(input.input, 1, length(input.input) - length(tld.tld) - 1)) as output 
from input inner join tld 
on input.input like concat('%.', tld.tld) group by input.input;
```

**OR**, if you only have a single value for `input`, then:

```
set @input = 'alpha.co.uk';

select min(substring(@input, 1, length(@input) - length(tld.tld) - 1)) as output
from tld
where @input like concat('%.', tld.tld);
```

Comment: What would that look like if `input` was a single variable, not a table?